# Are the physical properties of Tin-coated metals the same as of the substrate?

Tags: electric-current, stress-strain, physical-constants

I am trying to perform a finite element analysis to plot static structural loading on a bare copper and compare the results with the tin plated copper. I do have the information about the electrical resistivity of the tin plated copper, but I do not have any information about it's physical properties. By physical properties, I mean, the Young's modulus, Poisson's ratio, tensile yield strength and tensile ultimate strength. Do they stay the same as that of the substrate (copper) or they change ? The coating of the tin plating is 20µm. However, I am skeptical if thickness in the order of few microns will really affect the physical properties. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

IEC 60943:1998 clause 2.2.4, mentions that if one metal is thinly plated onto another, the hardness must be taken as that of the plating and resistivity as that of the base metal.

Comment: "*I read in one of the journal that the yield strength was changed when the substrate was coated with specific thickness.*" This is not helpful without the source to provide the context and assumptions. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

~micron-thick coatings will not affect the physical properties of the base metal. Just use the data for the copper sheet.

Note that if the coating was applied via *electroplating*, it is possible to embrittle the base metal with hydrogen if the plating process was poorly-controlled.